# Creating a Response page of if Donation is successful or not

Tags: javascript, html

I seriously need help, so here is my story.
I created a website for a certain organization, this organization wanted a provision on their site that could allow people to donate online, so I introduced them to this company that offer payment gateways.
The company that gives payment gateways has asked me to create a web page that will be displaying the results, i.e either the donation is successful or not. This webpage should have the parameters that the company will be passing. And these parameters are response_code, response_description, and result. The results will either be successful or failed.
The response code will be changing and will be accompanied by a response description.
For example of the donation failed to go through, a page that says the donation failed, it displays the code and the description I.e, the reason it failed.

I don't really understand how to go about it, I am an a mature at this, I am actually still learning, and I don't know JavaScript too well. But just an explaination of how I should  go about it will be highly appreciated.
Thank you. I will be happy to provide more information about this.

Comment: Your web page will need to have javascript in it; in a function in there it could read the parameters from the URL and then dynamically add html into the page to show them etc. This is very basic stuff and I doubt someone will explain too much here as it is all found by googling.

Comment: Thank you so Chris. That opens my mind up a bit. If it is searching on Google how would you suggest I search? And if it is not much trouble kindly give me a simple example or illustration.

Comment: This tutorial is, I think, at a good level to start at for you: https://jennamolby.com/how-to-display-dynamic-content-on-a-page-using-url-parameters/